# How to update a customized process template to access new features in multiple Team Projects in TFS 2015 RTM?

Tags: c#, vb.net, tfs-process-template, tfs-2015

I read these links on the official Microsoft page *Update a customized process template to access new features* :

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/05/31/how-to-configure-features-for-dozens-of-team-projects.aspx
- https://features4tfs.codeplex.com/

When I try to execute Features4tfs.2015 in debug I get this exception 
`System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported. at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Integration.Server.CommonStructureService.Microsoft.Tea‌​‌​mFoundation.Framework.Server.ITeamFoundationService.ServiceStart(TeamFoundation‌​Re‌​questContext systemRequestContext)`

on this call

`ProjectFeatureProvisioningService.GetFeatures(...)`.

Any idea?

Comment: My first problem was finding the dll *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common.dll*, it was solved with the help of jessehouwing, see the answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution proposed by Microsoft to solve the problem with features4tfs on TFS 2015 RTM :

insert this line

```
deploymentHostProperties.PlugInDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), @"Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Plugins");
```

just after this line (line 68)

```
TeamFoundationServiceHostProperties deploymentHostProperties = new TeamFoundationServiceHostProperties();
```

After that it works perfectly on TFS 2015 RTM.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to live here in v14:

```
public class ProjectFeatureProvisioningService : ITeamFoundationService, IProjectFeatureProvisioning

Name: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common.ProjectFeatureProvisioningService 
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common, Version=14.0.0.0
```

Reflector is your friend in these cases. Just load all assemblies from the TFS server directories into Reflector and then use the search feature:

[image]

It'll then be a piece of cake to find the assembly "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common.dll" here:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Plugins

These internal classes can move between assemblies without notification. That's why they're internal ;).

*Full disclosure:* I received a copy of Reflector Pro for my blogging and love for the product. There are other products like IlSpy, justDecompile or dotPeek which may offer similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks , I finally found the dll "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common.dll" on the TFS 2015 server at these locations :

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Plugins

Comment: If you get it to work, please contact me on @jessehouwing on twitter :).

Comment: I get this exception
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.HostShutdownException
on this line
using (TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext = deploymentServiceHost.CreateSystemContext(true))

Comment: I can get past that exception by passing both the `/c: /w:` or the `/c: /d:` options with the right parameters, but then it crashes a couple of lines further down the code. with: `System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.  at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Integration.Server.CommonStructureService.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ITeamFoundationService.ServiceStart(TeamFoundationRequestContext systemRequestContext)`

Comment: But that's either an update to this question or a new question altogether and in that case, please award and close this one.